# Capture Nested HTML DIV Element Event via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, boolean, toast

In looking to make a small JavaScript application a little more dynamic, I need to be able to capture a particular event on a webpage, that displays an HTML toaster popup on the success of resetting one's password. It looks like this:

```
<div class="caxToasterMessageWrapper">
  <div class="cax-success-message">
    <div class="caxTitle">Success</div>
    <div class="caxBody">Save was successful!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's a few more `div` elements that encase this, but this is the focal point of what I'm trying to capture... If the the `div` element code runs or returns `True` that the **Success, Save was successful!** portion actually ran in the webpage *(meaning, a password was successfully set)*, I want to capture that fact  that it happened... `True` and then tell my JavaScript to run some code for an alert box to the user to proceed with some other steps I have for them after options in the alert.

Is this possible to detect such an event in the browser on a nested `div` element like this? If so, can someone instruct me as to how I might capture this event, and initiate my `alert()` based on returning a `True` value for this?

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from normal event handling, it makes no difference of the structure of the HTML to trigger the event. Although for nested elements you will want to prevent the trigger to bubble up parent elements. Also this is a bit broad.

Comment: No it isn't... it's very specific. I'm looking to detect whether the Success Toaster Popup was actually triggered, to 1) See the little popup having appeared on the webpage... and if that did occur... then,  2) Capture/Detect it in JavaScript, as to perform another based off of it.

Comment: Yeah, the html doesn't make a difference here...

Comment: Please include above the Javascript code you've tried so far so we can help you debug or improve it.

Comment: It's broad because you are explaining the problem without getting into any actual details on the code and it's functionality working. For example: *"If the the div element code runs or returns `True`... I want to capture that fact that it happened..."*. The code you claimed ran and return `true` is what is capturing that it happened by returning `true`, so what's the issue here? What have you tried, and why does it not work? What are the details of the actual event and how is it triggered? Have you tried using event handlers?